# Displaying database entries in text fields

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, jdbc

I'm trying to display database entries in text fields. The user enters the id of the record they want to update/edit and a button should populate those fields with the entries. My code seems legit and has no errors, but it won't populate on the fields.

```
 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String s = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS EmployeesDB";
            stmt.execute(s);

            s = "USE employeesdb";
            stmt.execute(s);
            String emid = eID.getText();

            s = "SELECT NAME, ROLE, CITY, SALARY, INCOMETAX, STATETAX, TAKEHOMESALARY FROM employees WHERE EmpID= ?";

            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(s);
            pstmt.setString(1,emid);
            ResultSet res = pstmt.executeQuery();
            if (res.next()) {
             //   eID.setText(res.getString("EmpID"));
                name.setText(res.getString("NAME"));
                role.setText(res.getString("ROLE"));
                city.setText(res.getString("CITY"));
                sal.setText(res.getString("SALARY"));
                inTax.setText(String.valueOf(res.getDouble("INCOMETAX")));
                ST.setText(String.valueOf(res.getDouble("STATETAX")));
                THS.setText(String.valueOf(res.getDouble("TAKEHOMESALARY")));
            }
            conn.close();
            pstmt.close();
            stmt.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get that right, you create a new database, use it and then query a table. That couldn't work since the newly created database will be empty. Or did I miss something?